# Only run write value at realtime database only once

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { 
  if (user){
    firebase.database().ref("users/" + user.uid).set({
      email:user.email, 
      points:"500",
      uid: user.uid
    })

     var query = firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid);
     query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
         var email = snapshot.val().Email;
         var point = snapshot.val().points;
         document.getElementById("points").innerHTML=point;
     });
```

The code above is for writing and retrieving the data from database,
but it is not going according to plans. Whenever there is changes on
points, it automatically restores points to 500. Is there a way where a user's data is written only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want to write the initial points if the user data doesn't exist yet. For that you can [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

```
if (user){
  const userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/" + user.uid);
  userRef.transaction((current) => {
    if (!current) return {
      email:user.email, 
      points:"500",
      uid: user.uid
    }
  })
  ...
```

This returns the initial value if no data exists yet. Since it returns no value otherwise, the transaction is aborted when data already exists.

Comment: Any way to get current user ID while registering an account?

Comment: Well saving data and retrieving data while user is authencated isn't going too well i edited the points of the user in database but it isn't updated in my site so I thought I would write data at database when registration and retrieve when authencated